# UIButton focus in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos

I am trying to understand how the focus is working when I have button inside Table.

The goal is to create a table view with custom cell, that has the same size as the table view size ( I want to see only one cell at the time ). When the button is getting focused, I want to scroll ( the table view is doing it automatically ), to the next cell and to see only the next cell.
I made sure that the button will be in focus and not table view cell, by override this method in the Table cell:

```
override var canBecomeFocused: Bool{
        return false
}
```

The button is focused and when I am swipe up/down, the focus is moving between the buttons and not the Table it self ( great success ) ... BUT, the table view is being scrolling automatically, and I want to understand why is some cases ( when the Table and Table Cell are bigger then 360 pixel )  it's scrolling to the next cell and I can see only the next cell ( the table view and the cell in the same size ) , and sometimes ( when the Table and Cell are Smaller then 360 pixel ) the table view scrolling just a little bit, until the next cell is showing only the button ( meaning the cell is not fully shown )

So , I have:

Cell and table view cell size are Greater then 360, we can see that when the button is focused, the table view scrolling to the center of the cell, and we can see only 1 cell:

[image]
Cell and table view cell size is Smaller then 360, we can see that when the button is focused, the table view scrolling to some point, when the button is shown

[image]

FYI: I think the size of the button is not effecting the scroll, only the table view and table view cell size is effect the scrolling.

Some one? any idea ?

[This is the test Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BftkihWPSaR1lCNmtFYUtoUGs): in order to see it better please change the table view size and the cell size to be smaller then 360, and make sure the UIButton is centered: [Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BftkihWPSaR1lCNmtFYUtoUGs)

Comment: Having a hard time picturing your problem. It's clear till you get the the "BUT" part. I have a couple ideas where it might be coming from, but more information would be helpful.

Comment: hey  @rugdealer I will try to explain it better. when i swipe up/down the table view scroll to the next button that need to be focus. if i change the table view size to be 360 and greater, the table view will scroll to the next button, and the cell will be centered. if i change the table view size to be smaller then 360, the table view will scroll to the next button, and the cell will not be centred. In general the purpose is to see only 1 cell after swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can put those methods in UITableViewCell's subclass. see

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment]{
    // Condition
}
override func shouldUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    // Condition
}
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    // Condition
}
```

you can see more at this link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/VikasPrajapati27/CollectionViewFocus)